# SwiftMailer, setFrom as a variable

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer

I'm using Symfony2 framework and I want to send a mail based on `setFrom` as a variable .

I mean, I want to replace :
     ->setFrom('send@example.com')

by

```
   ->setFrom($from)
```

By the way, I tried this solution which works with Sender and Content but not with From:

```
    $from=$request->get('from');
    $message= \Swift_Message::newInstance()
             ->setSubject($subject)
             ->setFrom($from)
             ->setTo($to)
             ->setBody($content);
    $mailer->send($message);
```

It only works with the mail mentioned in the file "parameters.yml"

thank you for your help

Comment: hi Emna, have you solve? how? thanks for share your experience

Answer (score 0):

try passing an array as follow:

```
        $mailMessage = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
            ->setTo($to)
            ->setSubject($this->subject)
            ->setFrom(array($this->senderAddress=>$this->senderName))
            ->setBody($body ,$contentType);
```

More info [here](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/messages.html)